# Join order differs for between two instances of the same Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, database, join, indexing

There is a query that I want to optimize. To make some tests, I took a snapshot of the production database and create a new test instance of this database. Using the `explain` clause, I can see that the order of the joins differ between the two databases. The two databases have the same version (MySQL 5.6.19a), the same engine (InnoDB), the same schema, the same indexes, the same data, and are executed on the same material. The only difference, is that the production database use more memory (obviously) because it has more connections to it.

What may cause the join order to be different?
The memory usage?
The indexes are still building in the test instance?
The indexes of the production database are fragmented?

Comment: What do you mean by *join order*?

Comment: If you have a query as: `SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B ON B.id = A.id_B JOIN C ON C.id = A.id_C` you can first join A on B then on C, or first join C on A then on B etc... Normally the engine try to determine the order that will limited the number of line to read etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rare but quite feasible.  InnoDB has "statistics" about each index on each table; it uses them to decide what it the best way to perform the query, including what order to look at the tables.

The statistics used to come from 8 'random' dives into the BTree to get a crude feel for the number of rows and the distribution of the data.  The timing of the dives, the number '8', and the randomness have all been criticized, and gradually they have been improved.  Only some improvements exist in 5.6.19.

Also the "cost" model of deciding how to perform the query has recently had an overhaul (5.7 / 8.0).  8.0 and MariaDB 10.0 have "histograms", which should lead to better query plan choices.  Not yet implemented (as of 8.0.0):  Noticing which blocks are already cached; this could picking a 'worse' index because more of it is cached, hence faster.

Because of the complexity of the optimization problem and the huge number of possibilities, there are even some cases where a newer version picks a worse query plan.

Even if you are running the *same* query on the *same* machine, the query plan could be different.

I presume you already knew that changing a constant in the query can change the query plan -- and do it for the better.  I have seen the same query come up with 6 different query plans, presumably due to different constants.  This can be annoying if you are doing `EXPLAIN` on a query found in the slowlog -- you can't be sure that that query plan was used when it was "slow".

We simply have to live with all this.

You *could* do `ANALYZE TABLE` to recompute the statistics.  But that can make things worse or better, depending on the phase of the moon.  It might even (coincidentally) make your two instances perform the query the same.

The real question is "did one server run your query significantly faster than the other?"  (After accounting for caching, other activity, etc, etc.)

When both of two tables in a `JOIN` are being filtered (something in `WHERE`), it is very difficult for the Optimizer to decide.  If there is also `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, it becomes even harder to decide.

If you would like to provide your `SELECT`, its `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, we can discuss details.  (But start a new question.)

Comment: Thank you, using `ANALYZE TABLE` to recompute the statistics help me to have the same `JOIN` order. For the information, it make things worse. But I wanted to be in the same situation, so it is ok.